# How do I write an imapfilter "does not contain" email rule please?

Tags: email, imap, lua

I've recently installed imapfilter. I have some simple copy and pasted rules that I like, such as this in my config lua file:

```
results = account1.INBOX:contain_from('git@gitosis.mycompany.com')
results:move_messages(account1.DontCare)
```

but the rule I really want is: *if my email is **not** in the TO field, move it to another folder*

Can I get an example of how to write this rule please? Since the scripting language is based around an actual programming language, I would imagine this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
results = account1.INBOX:not_contain_to('git@gitosis.mycompany.com')
```

or

```
results = not account1.INBOX:contain_to('git@gitosis.mycompany.com')
```

Comment: I dislike seeing downvotes without an explanation. Please, downvoter, if you read this again, explain why this answer is not a "good" answer.

Comment: I prefer when it is simpler like in this answer - but sometimes when you already have complex rules, it becomes easier to use subtraction: `initial = pwd:select_all() ; direct = initial:contain_to('me@example.com') ; indirect = initial - direct`